# Able to answer closed question if I was offline when the question was closed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, closed-questions

On the RPG stack exchange, this question specifically: [What is the fineness (purity) of gold coins in D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107753/what-is-the-fineness-purity-of-gold-coins-in-dd/107755)

I was able to answer the question 10 minutes after it had been closed.

I had begun typing my answer before the question was closed, but during the time that the question was closed, my laptop was hibernating while I relocated to a different room. When I brought it back up, the question gave no indication that it was closed, and it accepted my answer when I submitted it.

Assuming the Stack uses sockets to communicate with machines, it appears that, on a Socket Reconnect, updates are not being pushed and there is no second-level check on the server before accepting an answer.

Comment: Actually you have 4hr after the closure to send an answer. The UI block to answer but like in the mobile app there is no check while you write an answer. After 4hr it will be blocked

Comment: Ah, thanks. Learn something new every day...

Comment: even if you're online, right click on the button and remove disabled property will allow you to add answer